# HTML, CSS - Make text box width same

Tags: html, css

I have this page with 1st row having 2 text boxes and 2nd row having a text box. I want to make their width same, the 
below code works fine in chrome, but in firefox and IE (tested in IE9) width are different. How can I make the width same 
in all browsers?

[JS Bin](https://output.jsbin.com/rukikeruya)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="cnop" size="2"/><input type="text" name="cno" style="width:122px;"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="cpono"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Chrome**

[image]

**Firefox**

[image]

Comment: Inline styles are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to make alignment of input widths easier cross browser (it takes into account the padding, border, and content widths). It also makes calculations of widths in a pre-processor like Sass really simple.

```
input[type="text"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[name="cnop"] {
    width: 33px;
}

input[name="cno"] {
     width: 122px;   
}

input[name="cpono"] {
    width: 155px;   
}
```

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mshtacea/

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yours is similar to @ReLeaf, but your answer suited my code.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a `width` to all the 3 input tag, it is sufficient that the sum of the first two is equal to the value of the third. You must also reset the browser's input default styles.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="cnop" style="width:30px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"/><input type="text" name="cno" style="width:122px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"/><br>
    <input type="text" name="cpono" style="width:152px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your logic (30px, 122px and 152px), IE displays correctly but not chrome and firefox

Comment: You must reset all browser's default for input style. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the box-sizing attribute, set a fixed width on your form and percentage widths on your form inputs, everything should align nicely.

```html
<form style="width: 200px;">
 <input type="text" name="cnop" size="2" style="width: 25%;box-sizing: border-box;"><input type="text" name="cno" style="width: 75%;box-sizing: border-box;"><br>
 <input type="text" name="cpono" style="width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;">
</form>
```

Obviously it's best to put these style attributes into a style tag or your stylesheet but this is a cut and dry example of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using CSS to format your controls.

```
<form>
   <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="cnop" class="input1"/>
      <input type="text" name="cno" class="input2"/>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
      <input type="text" name="cpono"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

In a style sheet, add these classes

```
div.container {
   display: block;
   width: 200px;  /* or whatever overall width you need */
}

div.container input {
   width: 100%;
}
div.container .input1 {
   width: 30px;   /* or whatever width or percentage you need */
}
div.container .input2 {
   width: 170px;   /* or whatever width or percentage you need */
}
```